# how to find the maximum element in sorted and rotated array with the below code?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

i know there are lots of solution to find the maximum in a sorted rotated array. But below is my code and i want to modify these code to work on all the input. Right now on few cases, its not working.

Help me to find the bug. if any modifications are required, then let me know.

```
#arr is the list of elements
#length is the length of the list
#left,right and mid indicates the different positions of the array 

def find_max(arr,length):
    left=0
    right=length-1

    while left<right :
            if right-left==1 :
                    return max(arr[left],arr[right]) 

            mid=(left+right)>>1

            if arr[mid]>arr[right]:
                    left=mid
            else:
                    right=mid-1

    return arr[left]
```

This code fails for below output :  **arr=[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]**

For this output is 5 while it should be 7.

Comment: Please use explicit variable names, your code is difficult to read at the moment!

Comment: @CorentinPane, my bad!,edited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer finally with the help of **Trincot**.Here i am posting the answer for anyone who will look for it in future.

```
def find_max(arr,length):
left=0
right=length-1

while left<right :
        if arr[left] < arr[right]:
                return arr[right] 

        mid=(left+right)>>1

        if arr[mid]>arr[right]:
                left=mid
        else:
                right=mid-1

return arr[left]
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` switch will go to the wrong side (the `else`) when the subarray (between `left` and `right`, inclusive) is completely ascending. So you should check that particular scenario too.

This you do with an extra condition in your `if`:

```
if arr[mid] > arr[right] or arr[left] < arr[right]:
```

If the first condition is false then we know that `arr[mid] < arr[right]`. Then if also `arr[left] < arr[right]`, we can conclude that also `arr[left] < arr[right]` (if not, then this is not a rotated, sorted list). And so that means the sub array is completely ascending, and `arr[right]` is the greatest value.

So you can further optimise, and exit immediately in that case:

```
if arr[mid] > arr[right]:
    left = mid
elif arr[left] < arr[right]:
    return arr[right]
else:
    right = mid-1
```

#### How to break it down

There are only three ways in which `arr[left]`, `arr[mid]`, `arr[right]` can be ordered:

1. `arr[left] < arr[mid] < arr[right]`: the maximum value is `arr[right]`
2. `arr[mid]  < arr[right] < arr[left]`: the maximum value is at the left side of `mid`
3. `arr[right] < arr[left] < arr[mid]`: the maximum value is at the right side of `mid`.

Any other ordering would violate the condition that the list is a rotated, sorted list.

Comment: wow!,that answered my question,lastly the break-down was perfect.Thanks.

Comment: just one more doubt, i should be asking this in separate question,but am asking here,here i have used the base conditon : Left<Right and many times we use  Left<=Right. When to use which variation of Binary search?

Comment: It depends on the problem that binary search is solving. Here we know from the outset that the value at  `left` will never equal the one at `right`, since the array has no duplicate values. In the general case a binary search will compare a *given* value with the value at the `mid` index. You would set `left = mid + 1` when that value is strictly greater than the value at `mid`.